# post values in smarty - CS-cart

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I was handed a cs-cart project and i've been having some minor issues, I think i'm missing something.

given this (self explanatory)  code :

```
{if $smarty.get.mypin ==""}
    OK
    {assign var="my_pin_q" value=$smarty.post.mypin}

{else}
    NOT OK
    {assign var="my_pin_q" value=$smarty.get.mypin}
{/if}
```

So i'm checking if a get paramter exists, if it does i'm saving it to a local varaible, else i'm saving the .post variable(instead of of the get).

This is followed by  :

```
<input type="hidden" name="mypin" value = "{$my_pin_q}">
```

(inside a form ofcourse)
the issue at hand is that for some reason `.post.mypin` is always empty, even though it's passed correctly through the form.(I checked the POST request).

Is this normal? Does smarty store the request variables somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use comparison `$smarty.get.mypin ==""`. You should use `isset` instead. Below code should work for you (notice changed blocks inside if and else):

```
{if isset($smarty.get.mypin)}  
    {assign var="my_pin_q" value=$smarty.get.mypin}
{else}    
    {assign var="my_pin_q" value=$smarty.post.mypin}
{/if}

Value of PIN: {$my_pin_q}
```

Comment: Well the situation is that the form loads with a certain query string of mypin, problem is when you submit the form, the query string is removed. I need the form to stay POST, and still preserve the query string. The code i wrote is my attempt at doing so. --- I'm also not understanding the code you wrote as an answer, this wil assign my_pin_q to an empty string if it's not set.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, but you should have explained earlier what you want to achieve

Comment: I was a bit unclear you are correct, However as I did mention the POST variable isn't returned. `$smarty.post.mypin` is always null even though the form submits it correctly. The code I wrote in my question works logically fine, the `only` problem is that the POST is never populated with anything.

Comment: @Patrick Request data is automatically populated to Smarty. If it's not there are only 1 option. You change/unset some $_POST data in PHP. You should try to add `{$smarty.post|var_dump}` at the beginning of this template to have displayed `$_POST` data in Smarty. You can also `var_dump($_POST);` in PHP just before displaying this template to make sure they are both the same.

Comment: That's what I thought, I wanted to make sure because I was sure I was missing something.

Since I really have no clue which .php file is loading this .tpl file I'll check where the $_POST is being unset. var_dump inside the template provides an empty array, which means it's as bad as you said and I thought. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
{assign var="my_pin_q" value=$smarty.request.mypin}
```